# Are there any studies evaluating the impact of the Mathematics Vision Project?

Tags: curriculum

I have found very little online that compares & critiques the MVP vs traditional
curricula. Any suggestions & pointers would be welcomed.

The [MVP](https://www.mathematicsvisionproject.org/) is an implementation of Common Core Standards in the USA aimed at
the K-12 grade levels.

I have one child who followed fairly standard curriculum which was challenging from a mathematics perspective and provided a solid basis.

I have another child, two years younger who has been following the MVP. Frankly,
I have nothing good to say about it. I am surprised to find so little about it online. I fear that my second child's interest in mathematics has been irreparably damaged and the skills taught insufficient in comparison to their
older sibling.

Comment: Is your concern about the prevalence of contextual problems as opposed to drilling in solving problems already formulated mathematically?

Comment: @richard: I am interested in some measurements that provide reasonable evidence that the wholesale change in approach is based on some concrete studies.

Comment: @richard: This was not the focus of my question, but formulating problems  in a mathematical way is quite a different skill to solving problems. Requiring kids to do both at the same time seems to add to the perceived difficulty. Plus, some of the problems I have seen have various interpretations which can lead to different answers.

Comment: @copper.hat I have found a study on Common Core mathematics which indicated a marginal improvement over traditional curricula. I can only see teacher reviews of MVP. Looking at it myself it seems enjoyable, though a little sparse on practice problems. Can you specify what about it concerns you regarding your child's interest in mathematics? I doubt that your child's interest in maths has been irreparably damaged by the curriculum - I suffered through several years of Saxon textbooks which seem specifically designed to kill enjoyment but recovered fairly quickly after I started university.

Comment: @Richard: Happy to discuss that, but this is probably not the forum?